# Opening a file in a folder in Python

Tags: python

I want to open a file to write to.

```
with open('test.txt','a') as textfile:
   ...
```

It works like this.

Now I want this file to be opened/created from a directory called args.runkeyword.

```
with open(os.path.join(args.runkeyword, 'test.txt'),'a') as textfile:
```

t says it can't find test/test.txt  (supposing runkeyword is test).

I also tried by appending with os.getcwd() but it still can't find or create the file.

Any ideas?

Comment: This may be a silly question.. but does the `./test` directory exist?

Comment: Does a directory called `test` exist in the current working directory? Maybe you need to call `os.mkdir` first?

Comment: Did you check to make sure that the directory exists before the call to ``open``?

Comment: Yes it exists, and so does the containing file.

Comment: Try `print os.path.join(args.runkeyword, 'test.txt')` and compare it with the expected path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`os.getcwd()` is irrelevant on your work actually. Use `os.listdir()` to see every folder in a directory. If anything named by `test` before it may be problem.

A recursive function like this may usefull for you;

```
import os

def tara(directory):
    start = os.getcwd()
    files = []
    os.chdir(directory)

    for oge in os.listdir(os.curdir):
        if not os.path.isdir(oge):
            files.append(oge)
        else:
            files.extend(tara(oge))

    os.chdir(start)
    return files
```

Comment: The actual names are not test, this was just as an example. I will try os.listdir(). But the directory exists, and without the directory, the file writes in the same directory as the (sub) directory.

Answer (score -1):

```
file = open('test.txt', 'a+')
```

You should have 'a+' not 'a', the + allows you to append.

Comment: But it should append the things I write in it. Will it still do that?

Comment: `a` will also create the file if it doesn't exist. The `+` specifies that reading needs to be performed in addition to appending.